# i was trying to create a command to remind members not to spam but i am having an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

this is the code where am having the error.

```
if (sniper.enableremind == true) {
    setInterval(function() {
        return client.channels.get(sniper.remind[Math.floor(Math.random() * sniper.remind.length)]).send(sniper.words[Math.floor(Math.random() * sniper.words.length)]);
    }, sniper.remindtime);
}
```

and this is main file ***Sniper.js***

```
const client = new (require('discord.js')).Client();

// Customisable stuff

var sniper = {};

sniper.instance = 1; 
sniper.enablelogs = true;
sniper.enableremind = true;
sniper.spawn = 'chanel id to read';
sniper.remind = ['reminder channel id'];
sniper.remindtime = 5000;
sniper.logs = 'channel id';
sniper.botprefix = '>';
sniper.playing = 'Fortnite';
sniper.token = 'token';
sniper.owner = 'id';

// Text to remind

sniper.words = [
    "You are using commands for a long time",
    "please cooldown for sometime"
];

// Logging in to discord

client.login(sniper.token);

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity(sniper.playing);
    client.user.setStatus('online');
});

// Send text to remind server members

if (sniper.enableremind == true) {
    setInterval(function() {
        return client.channels.get(sniper.remind[Math.floor(Math.random() * sniper.remind.length)]).send(sniper.words[Math.floor(Math.random() * sniper.words.length)]);
    }, sniper.remindtime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, discord.js went through a major update, v12. In that version, `.channels` is a [ChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager), which doesn't implement `.get` like Collections did. To get a channel, you now have to [`.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) it instead:

```js
client.channels.fetch(sniper.remind[Math.floor(Math.random() * sniper.remind.length)]).send(sniper.words[Math.floor(Math.random() * sniper.words.length)])
```